# Bluetooth Speaker connection stuttering in 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth

I have 2 Bluetooth speakers. I recently am facing this issue where the connection/sound is lost for almost a second while using the Bluetooth speakers. At first, I thought there was something wrong with the speaker as it was very close to my HP laptop. But it happened yesterday on my second Bluetooth speaker too.

I tried to use this (at least 2 months ago ) https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level and have the Gnome extension which uses this library. It mostly doesn't work and only shows a battery icon on the top bar for my `22.04`.

Also, recently I noticed something while OS is loading, an error regarding Bluetooth.

Keeping this stuttering aside, it kind of works decently and I am able to enjoy songs and movies without much irritation.

It would be nice if there is any way out of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the latency of the bluetooth connection:

```
$ pactl list sinks
```

For me fallowing worked:

Install pavucontrol is you haven't already.

```
$ pavucontrol
```

- go to Configuration tab
- Look for your bluetooth device and play with Codec drop down menu.

for me switching from anything but LDAC(High Quality) works great. Good bye laggy sound :)

Using sony wh-1000xm3